# ios setup constraint to animate an icon

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, constraints

I want to perform the following constraint animation on a magnify icon

At the beginning I want my icon to be at the right of my screen and then move it to the left of my textfield :

```
 ___________________
|___________________|           O-

to
    ___________________
O- |___________________|
```

So what I did is setup a constraint A on the icon to the right of my superview at priority 1000
and add another constraint B on the icon to the left of my textfield at priority 750

then when I want to perform my animation I remove the constraint A so I expected the icon to move to the left of my texfield but it didn't move

How to do that?

constraint A:

[image]

Constraint B:

[image]

Some code of the animation :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

    self.view.alpha = 1;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    //animating the icon
    [self.view removeConstraint:_loupeSuperviewLeftMargin];//remove constraint A
    [self.view  setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        [self.view invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Try calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize on your view to get it to re-calculate the constraints.

Comment: Do you need the text field to move to the right to make space for the icon in its new position? What constraints do you have on the text field?

Comment: the texfield is centered in my superview, I want the icon to slide on its left. Calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me if I gave the icon (I used a button for my test) these 2 constraints to the label (the lower priority constraint could have any priority up to 749 -- if I use 750, both views disappeared),

[image]

[image]

Then in code, I removed the high priority one,

```
- (IBAction)moveButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.rightCon]; // rightCon is the high priority constraint
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}
```

Be sure that you call removeConstraint on whatever view is the superview of the two views that have the spacing constraint between them -- it is that superview that owns that constraint.

Comment: Ok I have the same as you except in my case for the first constraint the first item is the superview.trailing, not the button

Comment: @Mathieu, Your problem might be this line, [_searchIcon removeConstraint:_iconSuperviewLeftMargin];. That constraint between those two views belongs to the superview, so _searchIcon doesn't own that constraint, and therefore can't remove it.

Comment: I edited my post to add details, it still do not work

Comment: @Mathieu, are you sure that the _loupeSuperviewLeftMargin outlet is connected in IB?

Comment: @Mathieu, try this. Select the "Remove at build time" box for the high priority constraint. When you run the app, does the icon now show up immediately where you want it to be after the animation?

Comment: It crashes the app *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63881/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mathieu).

Comment: Ok it works I was not calling removeConstraint on the right view, thanks